# How to fetch an IP address of a socket inside a fd_set?

Tags: c++, networking, winsock

Hey Im storing all connected sockets in a fd_set. I want to iterate through the sockets and display the IP address.

```
ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
                ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &socketAddr.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
                std::cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(socketAddr.sin_port) << std::endl;

                if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&socketAddr, sizeof(socketAddr), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0) {
                    std::cout << host << " connected on port " << service << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &socketAddr.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
                    std::cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(socketAddr.sin_port) << std::endl;
                }
```

I use this way to display the info when a new client joins but this does not seem to work when iterating through sockets already in the fd_set. Im new to socket programming and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: the remote address the socket is connected to

Comment: The IP address of what.  The local address the socket is binded to?  Or the remote address the socket is connected to?

Comment: Sorry, the remote address the socket is connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are interested in IPv4 and the IP address of the connecting client (as opposed to the server-side IP address), this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

// theFDSet is a pointer to your FD_SET object
// maxFD is the largest file-descriptor value in the set
void PrintClientAddressesInFDSet(FD_SET * theFDSet, int maxFD)
{
   for (int i=0; i<=maxFD; i++)
   {
      if (FD_ISSET(i, theFDSet))
      {
         struct sockaddr_in addr;
         socklen_t length = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
         if (getpeername(i, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, &length) == 0)
         {
            printf("Socket FD %i is connected to a peer at IP address %s\n", i, inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));
         }
         else perror("getpeername");
      }
   }
}
```

For IPv6, you'd need to use `inet_ntop()` rather than `inet_ntoa()`, and a `sockaddr_in6` rather than a `sockaddr`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It was giving me an error that `inet_ntoa` was deprecated but I was able to get rid of it by adding `#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS`. But the `FD_ISSET(i, fdset)` is failing and its printing out the `getpeername` error.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `FD_ISSET(i, fdset)` is failing?  Do you mean it is returning false?  If so, then `getpeername()` shouldn't get called for that value of `i`.

Comment: Oh ya I meant the `getpeername()` is failing and printing the `getpeername` error for all the sockets in the set.

Comment: Ok I was wrong. It is failing at `FD_ISSET(i, theFDSet)`. I had the `else perror("getpeername")` in the wrong line. So the `if(FD_ISSET(i, theFDSet))` is failing.
"https ://paste. ofcode. org/ SKhXCeT6nAKeSj2jk7FsQM" This is the code if you want to take a look.

Comment: @D.Haritheesan How do you want to decide which sockets to call `getpeername` on? Just decide however you want do that and then call `getpeername` on those sockets you chose to call it on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz So lets say I have a server running and 5 clients connected to it. I wanted to allow any of the clients to use the command `!list` and it will list out all the other client IPs that are also connected to the server. But this is all very new and confusing to me haha.

Comment: @D.Haritheesan Then you should just maintain a list of clients protected by a mutex and add/remove clients from that list when you add/remove clients to the server. Then any code that needs to can acquire the mutex and look at the list of clients. You can't avoid the fact that you have to have a list of clients somewhere.

Comment: Ahh ok I was thinking something similar but I thought that the fd_set already kept a list of connected sockets so I could iterate through them and print out the needed info. But I will use the list idea.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz serializing with a mutex is only necessary if multiple threads might access the list; I don't see any indication that multiple threads are involved here.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner True! Then I wonder why this was ever even an issue at all. Keeping a list of clients is trivial and you already need it to populate the FD_SET.

Comment: I think using an FD_SET as your file-descriptor-tracking-data-structure is also possible, although as data structures go it's not a particularly nice one :)